# View in Native Activity

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to create an native activity in Android NDK.I have followed the steps given in following link
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html
As mentioned in the link the Activity is written in OpenGl and behaves like it.
But I want to add simple view instead of all in the native activity through OpenGl.
any way to add in view in Native activity through java code?
Please provide me any solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't using the Java APIs, if you are following the content in that link it's clear that your are mixing Java and JNI with C/C++, this means that the entry point for your manifest file is a Java class so your application is running based on a java thread and you are supposed to manage your UI with Java; with the JNI doesn't make much sens to code UI in C or C++, i'm not even sure if this is possible. You can code an entire Android application only in C or C++ with the NDK but this is not what you are talking about so i will avoid talking about this.

Comment: NativeActivity takes over the drawing surface provided to your activity. Using NativeActivity and Android views is effectively incompatible.

Comment: You *can* get a similar behaviour by using a SurfaceView, and doing all of your C/C++ code to render into that. But then you lose the framework NativeActivity provides

Comment: You can use PopupWindow as holder for views - here is example how to do it for admob: [http://www.dynadream.com/ddweb/index.php/Special_Blog?id=20](blog post)

Answer (score 1):

Basically the answer is no and yes.

no - with the native activity , android framework handles the display to native activity. so the native activity is responsible for init and draw the screen, not through the java code.

yes - you can design activity in java and shift part of your process into native code. by doing this, you no longer implement a native activity. but still use ndk and jni. if that's you want.